# How to write config.yml file in circleCI for java-maven based appium scripts? Unable to write configyml in circleCI for java-mave based appium scripts

Tags: java, appium, devops, appium-android, circleci-2.0

I have written scripts using appium java client and maven and i need to run the with circleCI
can anyone help me with this?

Below is the yml file I wrote but its not working for me

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk-node
      - image: appium/appium-emulator
      
      
    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
      
    steps:
      - checkout
      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run: mvn dependency:go-offline
      
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
      
     
        # run tests!
      - run: mvn clean
      - run: mvn test
    workflows:
    maven_test:
    jobs:
      - maven/test
```

here is the error it gave
Its showing the app is not present at given location but i have checked manually its there
is there a way to solve this?

```
Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find app apk at /home/circleci/project/App/eezy-uat-2.apk (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 38.57 seconds Build info: version: &apos;3.141.59&apos;, revision: &apos;e82be7d358&apos;, time: &apos;2018-11-14T08:17:03&apos; System info: host: &apos;8908ccb13df1&apos;, ip: &apos;192.168.0.3&apos;, os.name: &apos;Linux&apos;, os.arch: &apos;amd64&apos;, os.version: &apos;4.15.0-1092-aws&apos;, java.version: &apos;1.8.0_265&apos; Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver Build info: version: &apos;3.141.59&apos;, revision: &apos;e82be7d358&apos;, time: &apos;2018-11-14T08:17:03&apos; System info: host: &apos;8908ccb13df1&apos;, ip: &apos;192.168.0.3&apos;, os.name: &apos;Linux&apos;, os.arch: &apos;amd64&apos;, os.version: &apos;4.15.0-1092-aws&apos;, java.version: &apos;1.8.0_265&apos; Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver

      org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find app apk at /home/circleci/project/App/app.apk (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 38.57 seconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '8908ccb13df1', ip: '192.168.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-1092-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_265'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '8908ccb13df1', ip: '192.168.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-1092-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_265'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:336)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:88)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:98)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:94)
at com.eezy.generics.BaseTest.beforeMethod(BaseTest.java:132)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
... 42 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find app apk at /home/circleci/project/App/app.apk (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 38.57 seconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '8908ccb13df1', ip: '192.168.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-1092-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_265'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
... 47 more
... Removed 33 stack frames
```

Comment: Where/how did you check that `/home/circleci/project/App/app.apk` exists?

Comment: CircleCi is linked with my github repo when i creating yml its pushing it to my github repo and using that for exaction. I just checked in my repo and file is there.

Is there any other way to  make this work?